# Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm newby in ruby on rails, I have search textbox then everytime I type an apotraphe (') e.g testing' word ..... I always recieved error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's  word%' OR english_name LIKE '%testing's  word%' OR chinese_name LIKE '%testin' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `jos_store`.`id`) FROM `jos_store` LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id as store_replenishment, store, MAX(stock_movement) AS stock_movement FROM jos_store_replenishment GROUP BY store) AS replenishment ON replenishment.store = jos_store.id LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_stock_movement ON jos_stock_movement.id = replenishment.stock_movement WHERE (store_id LIKE '%testing's  word%' OR english_name LIKE '%testing's  word%' OR chinese_name LIKE '%testing's  word%')
```

can you help me with my problem.

Comment: Could you post the code where you create/generate the SQL request ?

Comment: You should briefly explain your problem to get right solution. Like include your code etc.

Comment: I have this error when I navigate to rails admin and try to edit one of my users.do you have any  ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping your apostrophe, eg english_name LIKE '%testing\'s  word%'

if you're using '%PHRASE%' and there's another ' inside %PHRASE%, it thinks you've ended the like clause and gives you an error - if you escape with the escape character, eg \', it should work: so with your error phrase, something like:

```
<snip /> WHERE (store_id LIKE '%testing\'s  word%' OR english_name LIKE '%testing\'s  word%' OR chinese_name LIKE '%testing\'s  word%')
```

Notice I've used '%testing\'s word%' to ensure it doesn't think the second apostrophe ends the LIKE clause

Comment: how do i put it here in my query? please help me it gives me a headache.. here's my query...

search_query = "AND jos_product.product_code LIKE '%#{ search_val }%' OR jos_product.name LIKE '%#{ search_val }%' OR pc.name LIKE '%#{ search_val }%'"

Comment: OKay, so you'll need to make sure that search_val has escaped quotes in it, so something like: search_val = search_val.gsub("'", "\\\\'") . Note you should put this BEFORE you use the variable in your search string.